# Does all asynchronous I/O ultimately implemented in polling?

Tags: asynchronous, io

I have been though asynchronous I/O is always has a callback form. But recently I discovered some low level implementations are using polling style API.

1. [kqueue](http://julipedia.meroh.net/2004/10/example-of-kqueue.html)
2. [libpq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335408/why-does-libpq-use-polling-rather-than-notification-for-data-fetch)

And this leads me to think that maybe all (or most) asynchronous I/O (any of file, socket, mach-port, etc.) is implemented in a kind of polling manner at last. Maybe the callback form is just an abstraction only for higher-level API.

This could be a silly question, but I don't know how actually most of asynchronous I/O implemented at low level. I just used the *system level notifications*, and when I see `kqueue` - which is the system notification, it's a polling style!

How should I understand asynchronous I/O at low-level? **How the high-level *asynchronous notification* is being made from low-level polling system?** (if it actually does)

Comment: If this question doesn't suit to this SO, can I ask for better place to post this question? (ex: other SE site such as Programmers or Unix & Linux...)

Comment: Interesting question. Not great for Stackoverflow format but I am not going to close-vote it... Because I would like to hear some answers!

Comment: "interrupts" is a word that's going to be extremely relevent

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the lowest (or at least, lowest worth looking at) hardware level, asynchronous operations truly *are* asynchronous in modern operating systems.

For example, when you read a file from the disk, the operating system translates your call to `read` to a series of disk operations (seek to location, read blocks X through Y, etc.). On most modern OSes, these commands get written either to special registers, or special locations in main memory, and the disk controller is informed that there are operations pending. The operating system then goes on about its business, and when the disk controller has completed all of the operations assigned to it, it triggers an [interrupt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), causing the thread that requested the read to pickup where it left off.

Regardless of what type of low-level asynchronous operation you're looking at (disk I/O, network I/O, mouse and keyboard input, etc.), ultimately, there is some stage at which a command is dispatched to hardware, and the "callback" as it were is not executed until the hardware reaches out and informs the OS that it's done, usually in the form of an interrupt.

**That's not to say** that there aren't some asynchronous operations implemented using polling. One trivial (but naive and costly) way to implement any blocking operation asynchronously is just to spawn a thread that waits for the operation to complete (perhaps polling in a tight loop), and then call the callback when it's finished. Generally speaking, though, common asynchronous operations at the OS level are truly asynchronous.

It's also worth mentioning that just because an API is blocking doesn't mean it's polling: you can put a blocking API on an asynchronous operation, and a non-blocking API on a synchronous operation. With things like `select` and kqueues, for example, the thread actually just goes to sleep until something interesting happens. That "something interesting" comes in in the form of an interrupt (usually), and that's taken as an indication that the operating system should wake up the relevant threads to continue work. It doesn't just sit there in a tight loop waiting for something to happen.

There really is no way to tell whether a system uses polling or "real" callbacks (like interrupts) just from its API, but yes, there are asynchronous APIs that are truly backed by asynchronous operations.